# Problemas para ejecutar un .exe desde un boton con java

Tags: java

Codigo.  tengo este codigo en un boton para ejecutar un programa que esta instalado en el computador llamado Sugarizer.Int que es como aparece el acceso directo. Pero cuando ejecuto el programa me sale un error. reviso la ruta una y otra vez y esta buena.

```
private void btnSugar1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

      try {
        // Ruta relativa al directorio del archivo ejecutable
        String rutaDirectorio = "src/vista"; // Ajusta esto según tu estructura de paquetes

        // Nombre del archivo ejecutable
        String nombreEjecutable = "Sugarizer.Int"; // Asegúrate de que el nombre sea correcto

        // Crear un objeto ProcessBuilder para ejecutar el archivo
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(nombreEjecutable);
        pb.directory(new File(rutaDirectorio));  // Establecer el directorio de trabajo

        // Iniciar el proceso
        Process proceso = pb.start();

        // Esperar a que el proceso termine
        int resultado = proceso.waitFor();
        System.out.println("El proceso ha terminado con resultado: " + resultado);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon siempre el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: Pero es que los nombres no coinciden... en el codigo esta con un *.Int* y en la captura aparece con *.Ink* `//Asegurate de que el nombre sea correcto` dice curiosamente un comentario por ahi.... ¿es por eso?

Answer (score 0):

Según veo tu proyecto, estás utilizando Ant en tu proyecto de Java. En este caso, todos tus paquetes ya se encuentran dentro de la carpeta raíz; por lo tanto, ya no es necesario poner src/ antes de cada paquete.
Tu variable rutaDirectorio quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
String rutaDirectorio = “vista”
```

Comment: No amigo tampoco.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, estás ubicado en el directorio de trabajo, no en "src", por lo que tu ruta debe empezar con "src/", si quieres acceder a una carpeta que está dentro de esta, no solo debes agregar el nombre, sino la barra inclinada ("/") para que el sistema sepa que se trata de un directorio y no un archivo, y para acceder a tu archivo... debes agregar su nombre (extensión incluida), por lo que tu ruta quedaría así:

```
String rutaDirectorio = "src/vista/";
String nombreEjecutable = "Sugarizer.Int";  

      // Ojo con esta linea, debes pasarle el nombre del archivo
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( nombreEjecutable + nombreEjecutable );
    pb.directory( new File( rutaDirectorio ));
```